# Meaning of "pumping lead into the pack" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "pumping lead into the pack" in the following context?

> In those days we had never heard of passing up a chance to kill a wolf. In a second we were **pumping lead into the pack**, but with more excitement than accuracy: how to aim a steep downhill shot is always confusing. When our rifles were empty, the old wolf was down, and a pup was dragging a leg into impassable slide-rocks.

Context: [*Thinking Like a Mountain* By Aldo Leopold](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Comment: Lead, as in a _bullet_? _Pack_, as in a group of wolves.

Comment: The “pack” is the wolf pack, and bullets are/were made out of lead.  “pumping” connotes how fast the lead was flowing into said pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To pump (full of) lead* is a synonym for *to shoot*<sup>1</sup> or *to blast*<sup>2</sup>.

The *pack* is of course a pack of wolves.

---

[1] Webster's New World Roget's A-Z Thesaurus
[2] Oxford Thesaurus of English